# Get all the records from left table with computed column value

Tags: sql

I have master table with structure :

T1

```
ID    Name
1     Cricket
2     Football
3     Golf
```

T2

```
ID    T1-ID    SomeNumber
1     1        180
2     2        180
3     1        195
4     3        195
```

Column `T1-ID` is foreign ket fot table T1, ID column. I want to get resultset for value in Somenumber for `'180'` like

Output :

```
ID    Name        ComputedColumn
1     Cricket     True
2     Football    True
3     Golf        False
```

I have tried using Left-Joins, Case Statements but didnt get expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left join`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t2.id is null then 'False' else 'True' end) as ComputedColumn
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id and t2.somenumber = 180;
```

Actually, that assumes that a row with `180` occurs at most once for each id (as in your sample data).  If such rows could occur multiple times, use `case`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.id = t2.t1_id and t2.somenumber = 180)
             then 'True' else 'False'
        end) as ComputedColumn
from t1;
```